# Converting dictionary to string and Removing quotes of keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Note: recommendations from similar questions didn't work

I have a dictionary in python looks like this:

```py
print(dic_test)
   {'name':'Tom','school':'NX'}

type(dic_test)
    <class 'dict'>
```

How can I get a string looks like this:

```py
print(str_test)
   {name:"Tom",school:"NX"}

type(str_test)
    <class 'str'>
```

Converting dictionary to string and Removing quotes of keys in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys and values of the dictionary and add them to the string in the format you want

```
str_test = "{"
for key, val in dic_test.items():
    str_test += key + ':"' + val + '",'

# deletes last trailing comma
str_test = str_test[:-1]

str_test += "}"
print(str_test)
```

Comment: `str_test[-1] = ""` is an error because strings are immutable

Comment: @kindall the joy of learning C++ and python at the same time! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works:

```py
str_test = "{"
for key,value in dic_test.items():
    str_test += key + ':"' + str(value) + '",'
str_test = str_test[:-1] + "}"
```